# finishActivity with request code not actually closing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm launching a file explorer and doing some processing on the files from the explorer. I want the file explorer activity to close as soon as I hit the "Select" button. However, it seems as though it first does the processing in `onFileQueueAvailable` before closing.

```
private Queue<DocumentFile> fileQueue = new LinkedList<>();
static final int REQUEST_CHOOSE_FOLDER = 59;

public void startChooseFolder() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CHOOSE_FOLDER);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CHOOSE_FOLDER) {
         fileQueue = new LinkedList<>();
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        DocumentFile chosenDirectory = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri);

        for (DocumentFile file : chosenDirectory.listFiles()) {
            fileQueue.add(file);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (!fileQueue.isEmpty()) {
        onFileQueueAvailable(fileQueue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain the problem in more detail. This doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

The file explorer ends as soon as it calls finish.  Its done.  For you even to have onActivityResult called its already over.  However onActivityResult is called before onResume and similar functions.

Comment: Hm, so no way to fix it?

Comment: What's your actual problem?  There's nothing to fix with this because there's nothing wrong, everything is running as documented.  If you tell me what's your actual problem maybe there's a way to fix that.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear, the problem is that the file explorer activity isn't being animated out of the screen before the processing on the files happens, but rather after

Comment: Call onFileQueueAvailable(fileQueue); in your onResume instead of in onActivityResult

Comment: Updated my original post with your feedback, still the same result